# The homotopy type of $S^n\times S^n\setminus \Delta$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\Delta \subset S^n \times S^n$ be the diagonal subspace. That is, $\Delta = \{(x,y) \in S^n \times S^n \mid x = y\}$. I need to show that $S^n \times S^n \smallsetminus \Delta$ has same the homotopy type of $\mathbb{R(n+1)} \smallsetminus \{pt\}.$

Also I don't understand what $S^n \times S^n$ looks like. I think it is something like a sphere, but I'm not sure. Please give me a hint.

Comment: Let's take the case $n=2$, where we can at least visualize $S^2$. Next, you can visualize an element of the set $S^2 \times S^2 \setminus \Delta$, as a pair of distinct points $p \ne q \in S^2 \times S^2$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Wouldn't that space be path-connected, and hence not homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ \textit{pt} \}$?

Comment: Its not true. For n=1 only you can see that torus\ a simple (1,1) curve is still connected.

Comment: I suspect the problem has been miscopied.

Answer (score 3):

The map $\pi : (S^n\times S^n)\setminus\Delta \to S^n$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto x$ is a fiber bundle with fiber homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. It follows that $\pi$ is a homotopy equivalence.

---

The above is a special case of a more general phenomena.

Let $X$ be a topological space and $k$ a positive integer. The $k^{\text{th}}$ ordered configuration space of $X$ is $F(X, k) = \{(x_1, \dots, x_k) \in X^k \mid x_i \neq x_j\ \text{for all}\ i \neq j\}$. In particular, when $k = 2$, $F(X, 2) = (X\times X)\setminus\Delta$.

If $M$ is a path-connected manifold, then there is a fiber bundle $M_{(k-1)} \to F(M, k) \xrightarrow{\pi} F(M, k-1)$ where $M_{(k-1)}$ is $M$ with $k-1$ points removed, and $\pi(x_1, \dots, x_k) = (x_1, \dots, x_{k-1})$. When $M = S^n$ and $k = 2$, this is the fiber bundle I described above.

Comment: How result will change if we take R(n+1) instead of R?

Comment: @BaimyrzaShamyr:  Since $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{pt\}$ has the homotopy type of $S^n$, this is consistent with Michael's answer.